# How can I take the f(y)th-order derivative of another function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, fractional-calculus

(R2011a)
Hello, (I'm new to matlab)
when using the diff function to take the nth order derivative of a function, one can use this syntax:

```
f = % some function of x %
d = diff( % function (f) to be differentiated % , % number (n) of times to differentiate %);
```

where n is some integer.

However, if I define a function of some other variable, namely :

```
s = ceil(y * (heaviside(y) - (2 * heaviside(y) * heaviside(-y))))
```

which outputs only non-negative integers, and then insert that function in place of n in the diff function, which looks like:

```
d = diff( % function of x to be differentiated % , s);
```

then the diff function will not differentiate our function (of x) s times, and will instead return some error on the line of where s is defined.

I am trying to create a 3D plot that displays the various s-order derivatives of and arbitrary function (of x), wherein each plane of the form y=n, where n is some integer, contains the nth order derivative of the function (of x).

How can I put some function of either and array or a symbol into the second parameter of the diff function in order to achieve what I want?

Thanks,
Mike

This is ultimately what I'd like to run:

```
% First we define x  and t as symbols, and y as an array.
syms x;
syms t;
y = linspace (-3,3);

% We also define a mesh so that we can late plot z as a function of both x
% and y.
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% Next we define some function of x.
f = x;

% Then we define the ceiling of the unit step function multiplied by y.
s = ceil(y * (heaviside(y) - (2 * heaviside(y) * heaviside(-y))));

% After that we define j as the sth-order derivative of f, where s is some
% integer
j = diff(f,s);

% Now we define the other factor of the integrand as L.
L = (x-t)^( -1 -y -s);

% Now we define the gamma function adjusted for our uses.
G = gamma( s - y );

% Now we define a function z as the integral from 0 to x of j multiplied by L with
% respect to t, all divided by G.

z = int(j*L,t,0,x)/G;

%Finally, we plot x, y, and z in a 3d mesh
ezsurf(z);
```

And here are the two errors I receive when I run it:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> fracint at 14
s = ceil(y * (heaviside(y) - (2 * heaviside(y) * heaviside(-y))));
```

Should I have different definitions for x, y, and t than I currently do? Also, am I simply using incorrect syntax or is there a bigger problem (regarding the errors) than I know?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You intend to take fractional derivatives in Matlab?  What fractional derivative are you considering?

Comment: I've generalized the Riemann–Liouville fractional integral with the Caputo fractional derivative so that for positive order the fractional derivative is taken and for negative order the fractional integral is taken.

Comment: You could also consider [Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956075/fractional-derivative-in-mathematica-maple)